# Strange behavior with Pandas median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
       b           c     d     e  f     g     h
0   6.25  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
1  32.50  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
2  16.75  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
3  29.25  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
4  21.75  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
5  21.75  2018-04-01  True  True  7  54.0  64.0
6   7.75  2018-04-01  True  True  7  54.0  64.0
7  23.25  2018-04-01  True  True  7  54.0  64.0
8  12.25  2018-04-01  True  True  7  54.0  64.0
9  30.50  2018-04-01  True   NaN  7  54.0  64.0
```

(copy and paste and use `df = pd.read_clipboard()` to create the dataframe)

Finding the medians initially works with no problem:

```py
df.median()

b    21.75
d     1.00
e     1.00
f     7.00
g    54.00
h    64.00
dtype: float64
```

However, if a column is dropped and then the `median` is found, the median for column `e` disappears:

```py
new_df = df.drop(columns=['b'])
new_df.median()

d     1.0
f     7.0
g    54.0
h    64.0
dtype: float64
```

This behavior is a little unexpected and finding the median for column e by itself still works:

```py
new_df['e'].median()
1.0
```

Using `skipna=False` does not make a difference:

```py
new_df.median(skipna=False)

d     1.0
f     7.0
g    54.0
h    64.0
dtype: float64
```

(it does for the original dataframe):

```py
df.median(skipna=False)

b    21.75
d     1.00
e      NaN
f     7.00
g    54.00
h    64.00
dtype: float64
```

The datatype of column `e` is `object` in both `df` and `new_df` and the only difference between the two dataframes is `new_df` does not have column `b`. Adding the column back into `new_df` does not resolve the issue. This only occurs when the first column `b` is dropped. It does not occur if column `e` is a float or integer datatype.

This behavior is present in both `pandas==0.22.0` and `pandas==0.24.1`

There is now an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25375) for anyone to try and solve this!

Comment: This is odd. Seems to be an issue with the first column being `non-numeric` when you drop `'b'`. For instance with `df['c'] = 1` there is no issue dropping `'b'`

Comment: I think this is a bug

Comment: Intresting. If substitute values : `df.e=1` than no disappearance is occured

Comment: It must be dependendent on types of columns. If we substitute columns `c` or `e` with `df.c=1` or `df.e=1` - no mystery ocurrs afterwards. Very interesting

Comment: I suppose it's a bug. And bug not in disappearance of column but in calculation of median on `object` column `df.e`

Comment: I copy/pasted `new_df` by doing `new_df = pd.read_clipboard()` . I get the exact same result than with `new_df = df.drop(columns=['b'])`. I guess it is the structure of the data that generate the bug (I was suspecting a copy/view issue).

Is there an issue on GitHub yet?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug. When we dispatch any df to `median`, this maps to the internal `_reduce` function. With `numeric_only` set to `None`, this computes the median by series, and ignore failures (for the `c` columns, for e.g. median computation will fail.) and accumulate results (see `_reduce` in pandas source core/frame.py). So far it is fine. But while stiching the results together through it does a check to infer if the results are scalar or series (for `median` it will be scalar of course). To do this check, it always use the first column (see `wrap_results` in pandas source core/apply.py). So if the first column calc failed and it was skipped, this check fails, raising an exception. This triggers the fallback method within `_reduce` of forcing the dataframe to numeric only (dropping any columns with `NaN`) and re-compute the medians.

So in your case, if the column c (or any other dtype where median computation will fail, like text) is in the first column, then all columns with `NaN` will also be dropped for the median results. Setting `skipna` does not change as the bug is with how non-numeric column in first position triggers a forced numeric only computation. I do not see there is any fix possible without fixing it in the pandas codebase. Or ensuring first column will always succeed for median computation.